# How to change HTML when <select> value changes with Pug?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a select element with multiple values and I need to use Pug inline interpolation to change the DOM when the value of `select` changes, for example (I'm passing 'apple' object to Pug via Express ):

view.pug

```
select 
   option Apple
   option Orange

//THIS PART DOESN'T WORK
if select.value=='Apple'
   h1 `${apple.price}`
```

index.js

```
app.get('/category', function(req, res, next){
  
  //define apple object

  res.render('category_view', {
    apple:apple //pass apple object to Pug template
}}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Please create a minimal runnable example or post it so a volunteer can repoduce it.

Comment: @Reporter alright